# ExecuteMultipleRequest - SQL Timeout Expired - Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

During development of a synchronous plug-in for "Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1 Online" I use `ExecuteMultipleRequest` to create multiple entity records. When I test the plug-in in CRM an exception message appears which says "SQL Timeout expired".
If I replace `ExecuteMultipleRequest` with `service.Create(...)` called in a loop it works fine. It also works fine if I change the type of the plug-in from synchronous to asynchronous without replacement of `ExecuteMultipleRequest`.
Does someone know what can be a cause of a SQL Timeout issue in a synchronous plug-in?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics CRM online is limited to the default setting of 2 minutes before a timeout occurs. This means larger processes in a single plugin operation are prone to timeout.

Below is a list of options:

- Review your code to improve performance
- Move the heavy operation from the parent to the child entity record
- Create a Queue entity with a type and operation which will fire the operation for each entity record individually

Good luck

Cheers

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your reply. I'm aware of limitations in CRM Online, but this one is not the case. As I mention before, if I change `ExecuteMultipleRequest` to loop with `service.Create(...)` it works fine. The plug-in is not heavy at all: simple operations and a creation of multiple records.

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for your response. Could you include your code and ommit all sensible information? In addition, are you sure that you are not reaching the maximum number of multiple requests? Did you try adding and logging timers?

Comment: It does not reach the limit of multiple requests, I am working on DEV environment and no one was working in it at that time. Possibly, I know what is the problem, this request blocks SQL tables and the deadlock happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the ExecuteMultipleRequest from within a plugin.  You're already on the server at that point in time, and therefore don't get any performance benefit from using the ExecuteMultipleRequest (From my own testing, I have not seen a performance improvement, if you have data that says otherwise, would love to see it).  You also run into the potential issue of having the request fail, [since CRM limits the number of concurrent ExecuteMultipleRequests that are executing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response and advice. Yes, I am on the server but still the plug-in works through the service, so it makes calls to it, is it not better to make one call instead of many? Correct me if I am wrong. Anyway, this is a good recommendation not to use it in a plug-in especially if it runs frequently, so the limit may be reached that can cause a problem.

Comment: You alone can define if it's "better".  I don't think requests from the same Plugin are executed on different servers.  I beleive it executed on the same server, so there is no http benefit from one request to multiple.